# PonyLang Windows CreateProcess FFI

Tags: windows, ffi, pony, ponylang

I've been trying to call Window's `CreateProcessA` from Pony Language's FFI.

I created both a C and a PonyLang example. The C example works great:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void wmain(void) {
    STARTUPINFO info={0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo={0};

    CreateProcessA("calc.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &info, &processInfo);

    if (status == 0)
        printf("%d",GetLastError()); // never hits

}
```

I put `calc.exe` in the current directory. This works flawlessly on Windows.
However, my PonyLang implementation keeps on returning a non zero `GetLastError`:

```
use "lib:kernel32"

primitive _ProcessAttributes
primitive _ThreadAttributes
primitive _Inherit
primitive _Creation
primitive _Environment
primitive _CurrentDir
primitive _StartupInfo
primitive _ProcessInfo

primitive _HandleIn
primitive _HandleOut
primitive _HandleErr

primitive _Thread
primitive _Process

struct StartupInfo 
    var cb:I32 = 0
    var lpReserved:Pointer[U8] tag= "".cstring()
    var lpDesktop:Pointer[U8] tag= "".cstring()
    var lpTitle:Pointer[U8] tag= "".cstring()
    var dwX:I32 = 0
    var dwY:I32 = 0
    var dwXSize:I32=0
    var dwYSize:I32=0
    var dwXCountChars:I32=0
    var dwYCountChars:I32=0
    var dwFillAttribute:I32=0
    var dwFlags:I32=0
    var wShowWindow:I16=0
    var cbReserved2:I16=0
    var lpReserved2:Pointer[U8] tag="".cstring()
    var hStdInput:Pointer[_HandleIn] = Pointer[_HandleIn]
    var hStdOutput:Pointer[_HandleOut]= Pointer[_HandleOut]
    var hStdError:Pointer[_HandleErr]= Pointer[_HandleErr]

struct ProcessInfo
    var hProcess:Pointer[_Process] = Pointer[_Process]
    var hThread:Pointer[_Thread] = Pointer[_Thread]
    var dwProcessId:I32 = 0
    var dwThreadId:I32 = 0


//var si:StartupInfo = StartupInfo

actor Main
  new create(env: Env) =>
    var si: StartupInfo = StartupInfo
    var pi: ProcessInfo = ProcessInfo
    var inherit:I8 = 0
    var creation:I32 = 0
    var one:I32 = 0
    var two:I32 = 0
    var three:I32 = 0
    var four:I32 = 0
    var z:I32 = 0

    var p = @CreateProcessA[I8]("calc.exe",
    z,
    one,
    two,
    inherit,
    creation,
    three,
    four,
    addressof si,
    addressof pi)

    if p == 0 then
        var err = @GetLastError[I32]() // hits this every time.
        env.out.print("Last Error: " + err.string())
    end
```

So the above code compiles for PonyLang, but `GetLastError` most of the time returns 2. Sometimes `GetLastError` returns 123. Other times it returns 998?
It all seems odd that the error code is different sometimes. Those codes all mean that there is some issue with file access?

`Calc.exe` is in the current directory (same directory as the c example).

Also not only is the Error code different but calc.exe is executed(runs fine) in the C version but not in the PonyLang version.  This leads me to believe something is off with my PonyLang ffi setup.

Does anyone know what may be wrong?

Comment: Your C code has the same bug as your PonyLang code and only works by coincidence.  You must check the return value of CreateProcess to determine whether an error has occurred.  Only *if* an error occurs is it meaningful to call GetLastError() to determine the error code.  If no error has occurred, GetLastError() might return anything, it is not guaranteed to return zero.

Comment: Right but the C displays calc.exe while the PonyLang, nothing. Thanks for the tip though. I will check the return value.

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that `BOOL` is an 8-bit type, it is actually 32-bit, perhaps that is causing trouble?  (Also a couple of the arguments to CreateProcess are of pointer type, so if you happen to be building a 64-bit  application they will need to be 64-bit rather than 32-bit.)

Comment: FWIW, code 998 definitely indicates a parameter error of some kind, it has nothing to do with file access.  (Are you sure that `= "".cstring` results in the field being initialized to a null pointer?)

Comment: yea so I even tried making those Pointer[U8] into just U64 and setting that to zero; didnt work, still 998. I also tried with empty string, did not work. But why would that even matter since StartupInfo is an OUT parameter it will just get overwritten, right?

Comment: Uh ... no, `lpStartupInfo` is `_In_`, perhaps you are confusing it with `lpProcessInformation` ?

Comment: But if your process is 64-bit as your last comment suggests, `z`, `one`, `two`,  `three` and `four` all need to be 64-bit.

Comment: No luck. Even after making every Pointer[U8] just a regular I64 and assigning 0 to it, still returns error of 2. Also making z,one,two,three,four all to I64=0 , gives me back error of 2.

I even went back to the C program and made those variables all empty string and it still worked.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a small C DLL that exports a function with the same signature as CreateProcess, and call that instead, so you can see the call you're making actually looks like to Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `addressof`. When you create a `struct` object, e.g. with `var si = StartupInfo`, the underlying type is a pointer to the structure (i.e `struct`s in Pony don't have value semantics). Then when you call `CreateProcessA` with `addressof`, you're actually passing a pointer to pointer to the function.

If your C function expects a pointer to a structure, you can simply pass the Pony object without `addressof` when doing the FFI call.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However; im getting error 123 now which means something similar to previous errors (invalid file name, etc).  MSDN mentions that this field is address to a struct (not a pointer by itself). If you mention that pony cannot pass concrete structs; should I just create my own dll with an easy interface and call to there?

Comment: Yes, implementing a shim C layer would probably be easier. The Pony FFI is still very barebones and isn't ideal to work with complex APIs.